# How to generate rootless DOM-elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In order to reduce the number of DOM-manipulations, I'd like to generate a temporary DOM, that I later on add to the DOM of the webpage.

In my case I'd like to chain elements, i.e. starting with

```
<span>.1.</span>
```

I'd like to add `<span>.2.</span>` resulting in

```
<span>.1.</span><span>.2.</span>
```

**Is it possible to add/append elements to another element, without having a root element defined?**

The only way I found so far, is using `add()` and reassign the result, but is that good practice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>TEMPLATE</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main">
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var mainRef = $('#main');

    // Using add() and reassignment works (but I have to reassign,...)
    var newElem1 = $('<div>foo</div>');
    newElem1 = newElem1.add("<strong>.1.</strong>");
    newElem1 = newElem1.add($("<strong>.2.</strong>"));

    // append() works with root element (I don't want a root element)
    var newElem2 = $('<div>');
    newElem2.append("<strong>.3.</strong>");
    newElem2.append($("<strong>.4.</strong>"));

    // creating element directly works (but that's not adding)
    var newElem3 = $('<div>.5.</div><div>.6.</div>');

    // append() does not work with an empty root element
    var newElem4 = $('');
    newElem4.append("<strong>.7.</strong>");
    newElem4.append($("<strong>.8.</strong>"));

    mainRef.append(newElem1);
    mainRef.append(newElem2);
    mainRef.append(newElem3);
    mainRef.append(newElem4);

  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements) this problem is discussed. The solution:

- add all elements to an array
- join the the array using an empty string
- finally append the joined string as an elemnet to your target element

This also works with text-elements. Try for example:

```
$(function() {
  var myItems = [];
  var myList = $( "#main" );

  for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      myItems.push( "<div>div-item " + i + "</div>" );
  }
  for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      myItems.push( "Text-item " + i + ", " );
  }
  myList.append( myItems.join( "" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for a `documentFragment`, which as the name implies is a fragment of a document, and exists to hold elements temporarily until you're ready to add that fragment to the document itself; for example:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    div = document.createElement('div');

// documentFragment not present in the DOM at this point:

fragment.appendChild(div);

// document fragment contains a child element,
// neither of which is present in the DOM.

// appending the document to the document:
document.body.appendChild(frag);

// the <div> is now in the DOM, the fragment
// itself is not, and no longer contains the <div>.
```

When the `fragment` is appended to the `<body>` only the `<div>` is actually inserted, the `fragment` is no longer present.

Comment: That depends entirely on what the OP means by a "root element," the documentFragment can exist outside of the document until such a time as it, or rather its contents, are appended to the document.

Comment: Since it's tagged jQuery, `var fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());`

Comment: @Ben: why? I don't really see any benefit of wrapping a `documentFragment` with jQuery , although of course you *can*, if it's wanted.

Comment: It may, if you store that in a variable, and log that variable to the console, it should tell you. I'm currently away from a computer (iPad), so I'm not really able to check. As I said in the answer, though, it seems that you want a document fragment, but it depends entirely on what you believe/consider a "root element," there will always be something to hold multiple DOM nodes together, whether it's a created element or a created fragment, if you want to add multiple elements to the DOM with only one redraw event.

Comment: @DavidThomas: wrapping a `documentFragment` with jQuery allows you to use jQuery functions (you can use `.append()` instead of `.appendChild()`).

Comment: What's the reason for my question beeing voted down? Nobody wrote a comment on that. Is it because I mentioned jQuery?